# Using 2 Logitech unifying receivers lists 2 keyboards and mice in device manager

Tags: device-manager, wake-up, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I am using 2 Logitech unifying receivers, one for the Logitech wireless keyboard and one for the Logitech wireless mouse. And I get the following duplicate devices in the device manager:

[image]

And the only setup that allows the keyboard only to wake up the computer (as desired) is setting the second keyboard device in the list to `Allow this device to wake up the computer` and disabling that option for everything else, including the 2 mice. As a side note, the properties for both keyboards reports the manufacturer as Logitech. But, for both mice, it's reported as Microsoft. How can I fix the duplicate device and incorrect manufacturer problems?

BTW, I have to use 2 receivers because putting both the keyboard and mouse on one receiver causes Windows to make both devices wake the PC, regardless of which is set to wake the PC. Thanks.

Comment: If you do not use either device (not useful without your computer) , then what difference does it make which device wakes up the computer? I would definitely just use one receiver. I do this myself and we do this for all client computers using the LogiTech receiver.

Comment: @John I am actually using both devices, but I just want the keyboard only to wake the computer. I don't want to set the mouse to wake the PC, because even a slight bump to the desk wakes it up, unlike the keyboard which wakes the PC only after a key press. Again, putting both devices on one receiver causes both to wake the PC, regardless of which is set to wake it up. BTW, both are Logitech devices. But, the only problem I want to solve now is the fact that there are duplicate keyboards and mice listed in the device manager. Right now, the keyboard only is waking the PC, as desired. Thanks.